# How to show that $S(U)$ is invariant under $T$ based on the following assumption?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-theory

Let $S,T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that $ST=TS$. If $U$ is subspace of $V$ invariant under $T$, show that $S(U)$ is invariant under $T.$

If $U$ is subspace of $V$ invariant under $T$, then $T(U)\in U$. Want to show $T(S(U))\in S(U)$. Since $T$ and $S$ commute, then $T(S(U))\in S(U)$ iff $S(T(U))\in S(U)$. Since $U$ is invariant under assumption, the image of $S(T(U))$ is in $S(U)$. But I feel my explanation messy. Could someone clarify.

Comment: You're using $\in$ where you should be using $\subset$ or $\subseteq$

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would answer:

Note that since $T(U) \subset U$, we have
$$
T(S(U)) = [TS](U) = [ST](U) = S(T(U)) \subset S(U)
$$
the conclusion follows.